# replace vb.net query with SQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a scenario that i need to extract remark from the database table and display it, in such a way that

- if length of remark is greater than 20 then
- Display the first 18 characters and attach `...` with the remark

For this i am using the following code

```
 Dim SQL As String="Select * from MyTable where id='2'"
 Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand(SQL,con)
 con.Open()
 Dim reader As OdbcDatareader= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
 If reader.HasRows then
    Dim content As String = reader.Item("remark")
    If Len(content) > 20 Then
       content = content.Substring(0, 20) & ".."
    End If
    ' read remaining rows
 End If
```

All works fine, my doubt is that can i use this operation in query itself?

```
    If Len(content) > 20 Then
       content = content.Substring(0, 20) & ".."
    End If
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this query :

```
SELECT *, 
if (CHAR_LENGTH(remark)<20,remark,concat(SUBSTRING(remark,1,18), '..')) 
AS 'Remarks'  FROM Mytable WHERE id=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in the query:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    CASE 
       WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(remark) > 20 THEN CONCAT(LEFT(remark, 18), '...') 
       ELSE remark 
    END AS remark 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE id=2
```